# How to insert extra space between chapters in the LoF/LoT in the komabook class without calling \chapter{...}?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, tocbasic, kaobook

I am using the [kaobook](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/kaobook) template for my PhD thesis. It can be found [here](https://www.overleaf.com/docs?snip_uri=https://www.latextemplates.com/actions/action_download_template?template=kaobook-overleaf) on Overleaf.

Due to design reasons, I do not call `\chapter{...}`, but simply increment the chapter counter manually. Because I never call `\chapter`, there is no space between the chapters in the ToF and ToT (see attached picture). Can I somehow "fake-call" `\chapter`, or redefine the section command (which is already redefined in the `kao.sty` file) to get the space back?

I tried to look for a solution, but most other questions are interested in **removing** the extra space, and don't have to deal with the problem of never having declared a new chapter.

[image]

Comment: \i don't go near Overleaf. Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows what you have done and what the problem is. (What iare ToF and  ToT?)

Comment: I figured that if ToC = Table of Contents, then surely ToF = Table of Figures. Apparently that is LoF though.

Comment: But the LaTeX commands are `listoffigures` and `\listoftables` which create "List of Figures" and "List of Tables".

Comment: You have still not provided an MWE so we don't know what you have done and therefor the cause of your problem is a mystery. --- GOM

Comment: I don't think an MWE is feasible for me here. I would need to take apart the whole template, and this would take days. Even more so, I don't think it is necessary, as the whole code is just there, if one were to follow the link. No idea why Overleaf is a problem, but I guess that is another philosophical discussion. But I solved the problem myself anyway, just keeping the question here for posterity.

Comment: As I said I don't go near overleaf. You don't have to take the whole template apart. What we want is `\documentclass... % your preamble % your document code \end{document}` as I said in my initial comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While surely not the most elegant answer, this is how I did it. I added the two lines below, between the two sections that I wanted to split (i.e., at the start of the second and third chapter/part). The `0.7` is a manual tweak, I couldn't figure out the exact spacing in the template.

```
\addtocontents{lof}{\vspace{0.7\normalbaselineskip}} 
\addtocontents{lot}{\vspace{0.7\normalbaselineskip}}
```